# Deleting all in a Binary Tree producing random Segmentation Faults

Tags: c, recursion, binary-tree

So I have a completed program that adds values into a binary tree. It then can list values in pre-order, post-order, and in order. Now everything works very dandy, except when I run my `deleteAll` function it makes the program unstable, and randomly when adding values, or listing the tree it can produce a segmentation fault. I'm not exactly sure what's wrong, I'm still new to **C**, and cannot grasp what is causing it. It's obviously in the `deleteAll`function, so here it is...

```
void deleteAll(node* *hd){
    node* curr = *hd;
    if(curr->left != NULL){
        deleteAll(&curr->left);
    }
    if(curr->right != NULL){
        deleteAll(&curr->right);
    }
    free(curr);
}
```

After I delete all and list in any order it will give me values such as 321294124, you know values given when it's non-existant. So I assume that's okay, but maybe that's the problem.

Comment: I guess you forgot to set something to `NULL`.

Comment: *hd = NULL; Is that correct?

Comment: Can you give some info about the argument you are passing to function "deleteAll"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void deleteAll(node* *hd){
if(*hd != NULL){
    node* curr = *hd;
    if(curr->left != NULL){
        deleteAll(&curr->left);
    }
    if(curr->right != NULL){
        deleteAll(&curr->right);
    }
    free(curr);
    *hd = NULL;
}
}
```

Figured it out, thanks arrowdodger.